# font-awesome vertical alignment issue

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've been playing around with font awesome for some time now, and there's a problem I just can't wrap my head around.

I've made this simple JSfiddle to show the alignment problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Laukess/fnssktu7/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>    
    <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

i {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

As you can see, the icons don't align vertically. The heart icon seems to be in the middle, but the messages icon seem to have white space at the top, and the next icon (external-link) seems to have white space at the bottom.

What am I doing wrong? Why wouldn't the icon designers distribute the white space evenly if the icon is shorter than its width?

I'm quite puzzled, can't find anything using google, so I imagine it's just me making a beginner mistake, so I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Keep in mind the browser treats these icons as text as font-awesome is a font. The white space varies just like the "j" character has white space different from the "i" character. To manipulate their sizes individually it should be done with `font-size` either inline or using the css selector `i.fa`, not `height` or `width` on the selector `i`

Comment: I agree with @Brian your CSS code should [look more like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fnssktu7/9/) notice I am not setting width and height but instead font-size and line-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fnssktu7/7/).

As you said, it is the fault of the icons' designers. You can fix it using negative / positive margins:

```
.fa-comments-o {
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.fa-external-link {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Even though I would have hoped this wasn't the answer, it seems like it is. Thanks for your input, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I went and checked out the actual font files and several of the glyphs are centered on different heights. You haven't made any mistakes. The only thing you can really do is use what [TechWisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3140273/techwisdom) suggested in his answer. Alter the margin-top attribute to adjust the heights of glyphs that don't line up vertically the way you want.